# basic requirements to be called RTOS for 8051

Tags: operating-system, embedded, microcontroller, rtos, 8051

I want to make an RTOS for 8051 and very confused as what minimum requirements should be followed to make an OS in 8051 as 8051 has very limitted resources in case of RAM and ROM. It is just and assignment type problem but i am really confused as we make softwares for 8051 are they not an OS? which features differenciate a normal regular coding of micro controller from RTOS? please help thanks

Comment: An operating system doesn't have to be multi-megabyte behemoth, it can be defined as [a collection of software that manages computer hardware resources and provides common services for computer programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system).  Have a look at [Femto OS](http://www.femtoos.org/) that has a footprint of a few k and is designed to be on microcontrollers with a size comparable to your 8051

Comment: Thank you so much, Femto OS i think is what i was looking for. I am going through this. Thanks

Comment: @fvu: Your comment looks a lot like an answer, consider posting it as such.

Answer (score 4):

An typical RTOS provides at least the following:

- Deterministic task scheduling
- Task synchronisation mechanisms
- Inter-process communication mechanisms
- Timer services

An RTOS scheduler is typically priority-based and pre-emptive - the highest priority task that is ready to run will run, regardless of the state of lower priority tasks.

There is a presentation by [Jack Ganssle on RTOS Fundamentals on TechOnline](http://www.techonline.com/education-training/fundamentals/4213896/Fundamentals-of--Real-Time-Operating-Systems) that may be of use to you.  It is sponsored by Micrium and uses uC/OS-II as a case study, but it generally applicable for the most part.

The 8051 in particular is capable of particularly efficient task context switching due to its multiple register banks, switchable with a single instruction.

Comment: @califford.... Thanks for explaining the minimum tasks, one more thing, what about the tasks? should it be hard coded into RTOS code or should it be left for users to write their task on run time? that is very confusing to me now

Comment: @AbdulRehman:  I am not sure what you mean, but an RTOS provides the means to create and schedule tasks, but you write the tasks.  Typically this will be a function  that loops indefinitely waiting on some scheduling event (message, timer, semaphore etc.) then processing it. The "create task" function will take as one of its parameters a pointer to your task function.

Answer (score 1):

The [functionality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_operating_system) of an RTOS are largely guided by its ability to execute a particular work-load in a deterministic and timely manner.  These usually include threading, synchronisation operations and a scheduler with a specialised algorithm designed to execute threads in a deterministic fashion.

Implementing this in a 8051 is going to be a tall-order (and perhaps even impossible due to the hardware architecture of the processor).   A more common approach on uCs of this class is to use a [Cyclic Executive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_executive) and the priority nesting of interrupt handlers to enforce the priority of execution.  You could consider this approach to be an RTOS of sorts.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me with the term Cyclic Executive, Actually that was term i want to know the differences between the cyclic execution and OS approach.

Comment: On the contrary an RTOS on an 8051 is entirely possible.  Its multiple switchable register banks make context switches very simple and fast.  I first used an RTOS (Intel iDCX-51) on 8051 in about 1990. Both FreeRTOS and uC/OS-II have 8051 ports.

Comment: @Clifford - stack space, as in 'there isn't enough for more than maybe a couple threads, unless you swap the stack out into xdata on each context change'.

Comment: @MartinJames I seem recall a very similar arrange on an RTOS built for a Siemens C165 uC that I worked on in the past.  Somewhat screws up the latency of signalling a RT thread from an interrupt!

Comment: @AbdulRehman just for the record, I definitely don't recommend the cyclic executive approach!  Aside from obvious drawbacks (having do any anything that is time critical in interrupts, and then everything else co-operating in the cyclic executive) - there are practical problems of lack of modularity resulting in any moderately complex system having turning rapidly into spaghetti.

Comment: @MartinJames: I didn't say that it was not severely constrained, merely that it was not impossible or even impractical and entirely suitable for some tasks.  It certainly would not be my first choice for an RTOS, but When I used iDCX-51 (way back), I think it was an 8044 (a '51 with a BITBUS interface) we had a tx and rx task for BITBUS and "in" and "out" tasks for a dual-port RAM interface to a main processor.