# How could i do multi threading in embedded programmes?

Tags: multithreading, embedded, 8051

Hi i am an embedded programmer. Recently we came across a project where we are forced to use multi threading. I have used the same in java but i could not implement it my embedded code for 8051. Could any body please help me?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Please add appropriate tags.

Comment: Google: *coroutines* for an alternative.  You should express more of the underlying problem.  Why do you think you need threads?  Are you saying you wish to do this on an 8051 or that you previously coded on an 8051?

Comment: There are a number of real-time scheduling kernels/RTOSes for 8051, including SMX, FreeRTOS, uC/OS-II, CMX and many more. Search "8051 RTOS".  Invariably thee are libraries with C APIs that provide preemptive thread/task creation and context switching and task synchronisation and communication primitives.

Answer (score 5):

Threading requires that there be some mechanism to switch threads, typically called a scheduler.

Broadly speaking, there are two types of threading: cooperative, and pre-emptive.

In cooperative threading, each thread does some work and then transfers control back to the scheduler.  This is almost like having a grand while(1) {} loop as a program structure, only with more independence (only during development) of the tasks.  It still suffers from the risk of one task hogging the CPU, or even locking up and preventing anything else from running.  In effect, the independence between tasks is only an illusion or organizational abstraction for the developer.

In pre-emptive multi-tasking, the scheduler (likely driven from a timer interrupt) periodically *forces* a change of tasks by grabbing execution out of one thread, saving its state, and restarting a different frozen thread.  This is a little trickier to set up, but a lot more reliable.

Often with either scheme, you would not write the infrastructure from scratch, but instead would use a primitive operating system or at least scheduler routine developed by others.

For a very small embedded system though, you can also consider that interrupt service routines can themselves provide something akin to alternate threads for handling certain brief and/or urgent tasks.  If your serial interrupt fires, you grab some character(s) and store them for later interpretation at a convenient time by something else.  Many tasks can be implemented by using interrupts to deal with the immediate part, and then doing resulting work at a later point in a while(1) {} type program structure.

Some might properly laugh at the idea of a scheduler running on an 8051 - though for an oddity of reasons, inexpensive little 8051-equivalent cores end up in some fairly complicated special purpose chips today (typically accessorized by huge amounts of banked memory, and powerful peripheral engines to do the real work), so it's actually not uncommon to see multithreading solutions with dynamic task creation implemented on them in order to manage everything which the device does.

Comment: OK, 8051 threads/preemption.  Laughing now... :)

Comment: +1, [Rtos on 8051](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14632355/basic-requirements-to-be-called-rtos-for-8051).  I think Simon Tatham [co-routine page](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/coroutines.html) may also be worth a try.  This is not *threads*, but allows a primitive version of cooperative context switching.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of the 8051 is not amenable to any reasonable preemptive scheduling.  At least the stack, and probably more, in the on-chip RDATA/IDATA has to swapped out to XDATA and it gets very messy.

8051 is good for toaster/washing-machine controllers.

If you want/need such functionality as a premptive scheduler, move to ARM.

Comment: This is not an answer.  Also, there may not be a choice - lots of interesting-function devices such as radios, USB fifos, etc are built around an 8051 core because it's an easy and inexpensive CPU block for an ASIC designer to toss is.  Typically when this is done, the firmware doesn't need to be high *performance* (because the data flow may largely bypass it) but it may need to have surprisingly high *complexity*.  Yes, it would be great if these designs all got respun with an ARM core or something like that, but those are more expensive to license for your ASIC.

Comment: Well... the OP stated 'forced to use multi threading..could not implement it my embedded code for 8051'.  If that is the tool requied, an 8051 is just about the worst embedded platform for it that I have experienced.  Sure ARM more expensive, and 8051 fine for many jobs that do not require a preemptive mutitasker, yes.

Comment: My point is that you can't assume the poster is free to change processors.  If they are, you definitely have an argument.  But many of the 8051 cores shipping today are not shipping in stand alone MCU's but rather as programmable controllers embedded inside more current and interesting specialized chips.  If you use such a chip, you are stuck with the 8051 core in it, unless you want to treat that like a slave and micro-manage it over a serial channel from your favorite ARM.

Comment: The first RTOS I ever used was iRTX-51 - fully pre-emptive and hard real-time. The independent switchable register banks in fact make 8051 very amenable to efficient real-time context switches - for a limited numeber of threads at least.